# Is it possible to enable hooks in Trac Wiki?

Tags: hook, wiki, trac

I just wonder is there any way to add hooks for default wiki editing actions in Trac. 
For simplicity, let's imagine I want to have something like pre-commit hook for editing pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Trac wiki documentation as an [exhaustive list of ExtensionPoint interfaces](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracDev/PluginDevelopment/ExtensionPoints). An enabled Trac Component implementing the respective interface may to all sorts of things.

Regarding your request [IWikiPageManipulator](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracDev/PluginDevelopment/ExtensionPoints/trac.wiki.api.IWikiPageManipulator) should be the one to use:

> The IWikiPageManipulator can manipulate and validate wiki pages before
>   saving or before rendering.